# Geoserver, how to show only grouplayer in WMS

Tags: geoserver

I have created serveral layers, they are combined in a group layer.
When I connect to my WMS it display all layers in the workspace. I want the group layer to be the only layer possible to add, it that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by memory, I would actually go and disable all the individual layers in the respective layer configuration.

This should not impact the layergroup you created with them.

If you just want to hide them from the GetCapabilities response, uncheck the advertise box.

Hope that helps,
Simone.

Comment: Yep, just dont advertise them. You won't be able to see them

Comment: Thank you! That made the trick, and saved me time! unchecked the Enable before when I should have unchecked advertise..

Comment: Glad that helped.

Keep up the good work!